# Sodapy HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm trying to connect to the *openpayments* data using the *sodapy* library.  I have previously been able to connect with my code as is, but suddenly, today, I have been receiving the error below.  I've checked that my *openpayments* account is still active and that I have the right key, but for some reason it's telling me there is an authorization error.

> File "C:\Users\nrath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sodapy__init__.py", line 367, in _perform_request
>       _raise_for_status(response)
>
> File "C:\Users\nrath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sodapy__init__.py", line 421, in _raise_for_status
>       raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=response)
>
> HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden.
>       The current user doesn't have access to this view

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, I figured this out.  It turns out the site had changed the URL for the datasets.  Not sure why that prompts a forbidden error.

Comment: It's like the publisher "hide" the original dataset and published it to a new location